# Maven project not building

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get Maven up and going so I can follow along and study the MongoDb for Java Developers Free course from MongoDb University online.

I'm brand new to Maven and am having problems getting it up and going. I'm getting error message:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project M101J: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

When I try to run `mvn exec:java`, I cannot figure out for the life of me what the deal is here. As I said, I am completely new to using (or trying to use) maven.

Here is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>M101J</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>M101J</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project>build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I feel as out of place as a scorpion in a nursery right now and could greatly use any help and advice to get me going. Many thanks to all.

Comment: The error message is actually pretty clear. As you are beginner you should read this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/) to have a clue about Maven commands, goals, plugins, deps, modules...

Answer (score 4):

you need http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html plugin

add this to your pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>package.yourclasstorun</mainClass>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```